# SQL Server Bulk Insert failing when called from .NET SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, bulk

I have a stored procedure which does bulk insert on a SQL server 2005 database.
When I call this stored procedure from some SQL (passing in the name of a local format file and data file) it works fine. Every time.

However, when this same stored procedure gets called from C# .NET 3.5 code using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` it works intermittently.

When it fails a `SqlException` is generated stating:

> Cannot bulk load. Invalid column number in the format file "c:\bulkinsert\MyFile.fmt"

I don't think this error message is correct.

Has anyone experienced similar problems with calling bulk insert from code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing the bulk insert? Usually, the problem (in this scenario) is whether "c:\" is the server's "c:\", or the client's "c:\".

However. from C# code, the simplest approach is to use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). This class provides direct access to bulk-insert functionality from managed code, including mappings (although I never bother with them).

If the file is something like csv / tsv / similar, then [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) is highly recommended. This provides the `IDataReader` interface that [`WriteToServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets.aspx) uses most efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was todo with the format file.
I am no longer using the format file and it seems to work 100% of the time now.
I specify field and row terminators in the SQL instead.

```
Declare @Sql Nvarchar(2000); 

SET @Sql = 
'Bulk Insert TestOutputPretest
From  ''c:\rawdata\bulkinsert\Segment1839204.dat''
 WITH 
      (
         FIELDTERMINATOR ='','',
         ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
      )'

Exec sp_ExecuteSql @Sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`Exec sp_ExecuteSql @Sql;` (100% working)

`exec(@sql)` is not very powerful as it has some limitations

Comment: Please don't add signatures to your post. They're considered noise and will usually be edited out.